# How do I improve Lua internal error messages to include line numbers?

Tags: c++, lua

How do I improve the error logging to include line numbers? This is for an internal error that's thrown as I'm reading a Lua file. The only error message I get is `attempt to index a function value`, no line number or filename.

```
void handleLuaError(lua_State* L, const char* msg, const char* filename) {
  handleError("%s %s: %s", msg, filename, lua_tostring(luaState, -1));
  lua_pop(L, 1);
  luaL_traceback (L, L, msg, 2);
  char* result = 0;
  if (lua_isstring(L, -1)) result = strdup_s(lua_tostring(L, -1));
  lua_pop(L, 1);
  SPDLOG_WARN("traceback: {}", result);
}

void readLua(const char *filename) {
  SPDLOG_INFO("readLua {}", filename);
  if (luaL_loadfile(luaState, filename) || lua_pcall(luaState, 0, 0, 0)) {
    handleLuaError(luaState, "Reading file", filename);
  }
}
```

I tried adding luaL_traceback, as you can see, but the only message I get from luaL_traceback is `stack traceback:`, no actual traceback. I read that lua_pcall can trash the stack, and that I need to do some debug logging when the error happens, such as in an error handler, and not after lua_pcall has returned. Someone suggested I need to use xpcall and provide a custom error handler, but I can't find any documentation or example code on how to call xpcall in C++.

How do I set a custom error handler? Or is there a way to just tell Lua to put more info in internal errors? When I see my particular error message in other people's StackOverflow posts, the error message (`attempt to index ...`) shows filename and line number, so it should be possible to get filename and line number with this error.

Here's the Lua file which is causing the error:

```
addAchievement({
  code = "AchNewCity",
  name = "A New City",
  text = "Welcome to NewCity. " ..
  "Your first task is to " ..
  "build some roads. Click " ..
  "on the Transportation Tool in the " ..
  "bottom left corner.",
  condition = "true",
  effect = "FRoadTool,FRoadStreet",
  hint = ""
});
```

Comment: `no line number or filename` Do you run a Lua script or a Lua bytecode with debug info stripped?

Comment: It's a script, not bytecode.

`if (luaL_loadfile(luaState, filename) || lua_pcall(luaState, 0, 0, 0)) {`

Answer (score 2):

If in doubt check for example in original source code. Lua has an interpreter [lua.c](http://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lua.c.html) that does exactly what you are trying to accomplish. You are interested in [`msghandler`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lua.c.html#msghandler), [`docall`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lua.c.html#docall) and [`report`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lua.c.html#report).

[`lua_pcall`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_pcall) accepts an index to message handler as fourth argument. It can be used to retrieve information about error's environment and so on. After `lua_pcall` returns you can't do that (stack unwinds by then).

Your code should look more like:

```c
int handleLuaError(lua_State* L) {
  const char * msg = lua_tostring(L, -1);
  luaL_traceback(L, L, msg, 2);
  lua_remove(L, -2); // Remove error/"msg" from stack.
  return 1; // Traceback is returned.
}

void readLua(const char *filename) {
  SPDLOG_INFO("readLua {}", filename);
  lua_pushcfunction(luaState, handleLuaError);
  if (LUA_OK != (luaL_loadfile(luaState, filename) || lua_pcall(luaState, 0, 0, -2))) {
     //                                                 handleLuaError's index ^^^
     handleError("Reading file %s: %s", filename, lua_tostring(luaState, -1));
     lua_pop(luaState, 1); // Pop traceback from stack.
  }
  lua_pop(luaState, 1); // Pop handleLuaError from stack.
}
```

Now, that's a rather simple implementation. You should consider splitting `luaL_loadfile` and `lua_pcall` to react accordingly to errors related directly to loading a file. Again, you can refer to interpreter's source code: [`dofile`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lua.c.html#dofile) and then [`dochunk`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lua.c.html#dochunk).

Additionally, the example above lacks most of important checks, especially test if [`lua_tostring`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_tostring) was successful, unless you are more than 100% sure that the returned error can always be converted easily into a string.

It seems that you have two states coexisting: `luaState` and sometimes `L`. I suggest looking into that, it may spare you some problems in future.

One more thing, in addition to [`luaL_traceback`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#luaL_traceback) you may also be interested in [`luaL_where`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#luaL_where). It's used internally with [`luaL_error`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#luaL_error).